# Determining precise value using imprecise measurements.

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, confidence-interval

Suppose an accurate scale reports weight rounded to the nearest unit.
If it reports the weight of an object as "6", all I know is that it could actually weigh anywhere between 5.5 and 6.5.
But I need a more precise value for the weight.

Instead I could weigh myself twice, once holding the object and once not holding it, and take the difference as the measurement.
I then repeat the same procedure with nine more people.
4 of us report "5" and 6 of us report "6", for an average result of 5.6.

And with 100 people, I might get 42 "5"s and 58 "6"s, for an average of 5.58.

If 5.58 actually is the correct weight, consider these results:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random
actual = 5.58
for digits in range(1,10):
    n = 10 ** digits
    sum = 0
    for i in range(n):
        test = random.random()
        sum += round(test + actual) - round(test)
    print(n, sum/n)

./weigh.py 
10 5.2
100 5.55
1000 5.58
10000 5.5871
100000 5.58281
1000000 5.580323
10000000 5.5802115
100000000 5.57997507
1000000000 5.5799838
```

The more people, the greater the precision of the resulting average, but what *is* that precision?

What is the formula that gives the statistical precision based on the number of measurements?

`f(number-of-samples, %-confidence) = decimal-places`

Or gives the number of samples required to produce a specified precision:

`f(decimal-places, %-confidence) = number-of-samples`

Answer (score 2):

Your idea seems to be that the fractional part of the weight of a person
(in pounds) is a random variable uniformly distributed on $[0,1].$
This is probably not exactly true but the actual distribution may be uniform enough for your purposes, and it seems like a reasonable thing to assume as an approximation of the actual distribution.

So let's say the weight of the object is $a + b$ where $a$ is an integer and
$-\frac12 \leq b < \frac12.$
And suppose you do two weighings of a person of weight $w + x$
(where $w$ is an integer and $-\frac12 \leq x < \frac12$),
with and without the object,
so that the weight without the object is $w.$

Then the weighing with the object comes out to $w + a + 1$ if $b + x \geq \frac12,$
$w + a$ if $-\frac12 \leq b + x < \frac12,$
and $w + a - 1$ if $b + x < -\frac12.$
Subtracting $w,$ the "weights" of the object are respectively 
$a + 1,$ $a,$ and $a - 1.$

Note that if have also weighed the object by itself to get the result $a,$ if you ever get $a + 1$ by weighing it with a person you know that $b > 0,$ and if you ever get $a - 1$ you know that $b \leq 0.$

But even without knowing the result of weighing the object by itself, we know that the result of weighing someone with and without the object is a binary function of $x$:

- If $b > 0,$ you will get the result $a + 1$ when $x \geq \frac12 - b$ and $a$ otherwise.
- If $b \leq 0,$ you will get the result $a$ when $x \geq -\frac12 - b$ and $a - 1$ otherwise.

Now consider a random set of people engaged in these weighings,
where the weight of the $i$th person is  $W_i + X_i$
where $W_i$ is an integer and $-\frac12 \leq X_i < \frac12.$
Moreover, assume the $X_i$ are iid random variables uniformly distributed over
$\left[-\frac12,\frac12\right).$

In the case $b >0,$ for the $i$th person we get the result $a+1$ with probability $b.$
In the case $b \leq 0,$ we get the result $a$ with probability $b + 1.$

In either case, we get the higher of two possible results with probability $p,$
where $p$ is the fractional part of the weight of the object.

So the series of weighings is really just a series of independent Bernoulli trials, each with probability $p,$ and the number of "larger" weighings is a binomal variable with parameters $n,p$ where $n$ is the number of people weighed.
The confidence interval of your measurement is the same as the confidence interval of a binomial variable with known parameter $n$ and unknown parameter $p$ for a given observed ratio of "success."
Note that you get better precision if $p$ is close to $0$ or $1,$ and the least precision when $p$ is near $\frac12.$
But if you also take into account the result of weighing the object by itself,
you actually get more precision for results that are *very* close to $\frac12$ than for results that are close but not so close,
because you know whether $p < \frac12$ or $p \geq \frac12.$

Answer (score 0):

The variance of the [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) from $a$ to $b$ is $\frac 1{12}(b-a)^2$  Variances add if the variables are uncorrelated, so the variance of the sum of $n$ variables is $\frac n{12}(b-a)^2$.  The standard deviation of the sum goes as $\sqrt n$ and the standard deviation of the average as $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$